# The Flutter bindings were initialized in a different zone than is now being used

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I'm getting an error related to Flutter bindings being initialized in a different zone.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MyApp app = MyApp();

// Run the whole app in a zone to capture all uncaught errors.

  runZonedGuarded(() => runApp(app), (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (isInDebugMode) {
      print(error);
      print(stackTrace);
      print('In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.');
      return;
    }

    SentryClient? sentryClient =
        app.myProviderKey.currentState?.sentryClient;

    try {
      sentryClient?.captureException(
        error,
        stackTrace: stackTrace,
      );
      print('Error sent to sentry.io: $error');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Sending report to sentry.io failed: $e');
      print('Original error: $error');
    }
  });
}
```

I've added

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

at the start of main() because of an error I encountered earlier which is

```
Unhandled Exception: Binding has not yet been initialized.
```

The above error has disappeared but the Zone error has cropped up. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it to inside the `runZonedGuarded`, like:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  MyApp? app;
  // Run the whole app in a zone to capture all uncaught errors.

  runZonedGuarded((){
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      app = MyApp();
      runApp(app!);
    }, (Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (isInDebugMode) {
      print(error);
      print(stackTrace);
      print('In dev mode. Not sending report to Sentry.io.');
      return;
    }

    SentryClient? sentryClient =
        app?.myProviderKey.currentState?.sentryClient;

    try {
      sentryClient?.captureException(
        error,
        stackTrace: stackTrace,
      );
      print('Error sent to sentry.io: $error');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Sending report to sentry.io failed: $e');
      print('Original error: $error');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Copied the entire code. I'm getting Undefined name 'app'. in this line ====>    SentryClient? sentryClient = app.myProviderKey.currentState?.sentryClient;

Comment: Had to put in MyApp app = MyApp();  -----again      just above SentryClient? sentryClient = app.myProviderKey.currentState?.sentryClient; to make it work. It works , but MyApp app = MyApp() now appears twice in the code.

Comment: @Earthling you're right. I didn't realize that you referred to app in the error catching code. Putting twice would not be the right solution. I am not sure but maybe you are able to move that one outside the `runZoneGuarded` like you had before. I edited the answer

Comment: @Earthling I made another edit. I think this is the better solution

Comment: Doesn't work. The "Binding has not yet been initialized." is again the issue.

Comment: This worked. A missed ? On my end. Sorry for earlier comment.